# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (js and php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, json

I've been solving this issue for days, hopefully anyone can help me with this.. (Trying to pass data from js to php). What I am trying to do is passing the `lostid` from HTML page then to js page, then js page post to php page, from js page then get the data from php. Problem occurs at: `json = JSON.parse(data);` in my js code:

*note: when I change the sql query to either delete or select all statement, it works, but select with where clause doesn't.

```
function clickedMyLostDetails(lostid){
var lostitemid = lostid;

$$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: 'http://localhost/API/RetrieveLostItemAPI.php',
dataType: 'JSON',
data: {LostsItemID:lostitemid },
success: function(output) {
              alert(output);
          },
  error: function(request, status, error){
    alert("Error: Could not delete");
  }
})               

  $$.get('http://localhost/API/RetrieveLostItemAPI.php', {}, function (data) {
        json = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i = 0; i < json.length; ++i) {
              document.getElementById('itemname').value = json[i]["lostid"];

              console.log(json[i]["lostid"]);

          mainView.router.load({
          url: 'LostItemDetails.html',
          ignoreCache: false

        });

        }

    });

 }
```

My php code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "lostfound";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

 }


 $lostsid = $_POST['LostsItemID'];


 $sql    = "SELECT * From lostitem WHERE LostItemID = '$lostsid'";
    $res    = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $lostitems = array();
    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($lostitem_row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($lostitems, array(
                    'lostid' => $lostitem_row["LostItemID"],
                    'userid' => $lostitem_row["UserID"],
                    'itemid' => $lostitem_row["ItemID"],
                    'venueA' => $lostitem_row["VenueA"],
                    'venueB' => $lostitem_row["VenueB"],
                    'venueC' => $lostitem_row["VenueC"],
                    'lostdate' => $lostitem_row["LostDate"],
                    'losttimefrom' => $lostitem_row["LostTimeFrom"],
                    'losttimeto' => $lostitem_row["LostTimeTo"],
                    'imageid' => $lostitem_row["Image"],
                    'desc' => $lostitem_row["Description"],
                    'expdate' => $lostitem_row["ExpiryDate"]
                ));
        } 
    } 

    $json = json_encode($lostitems);
    echo ($json);


 mysqli_close($conn);

  ?>
```

Comment: trys add the content type **contentType: "application/json",** in you json query

Comment: what is the raw response from the server in the get() request? I suspect whatever it is does not parse as JSON...

Comment: You're using echo and print_r, so even if you had valid json, it would be rendered invalid

Comment: @TemaniAfif where to add?

Comment: like you add this **dataType: 'JSON',**

Comment: @NeilHibbert lostid is passed using json from another page in html, I've did the similar thing for another function, the passing id to js page should not have problem since the other function works successfully

Comment: added my anwser with more detail, hope it helps

Comment: @GeorgeCrimson that's fine, but what HTTP response are you getting from the server? i.e. if you made the same get request to http://localhost/API/RetrieveLostItemAPI.php in PostMan or Fiddler, what is the response message?

Comment: @NeilHibbert still the same though.. but when I try delete query, it works though, not sure if the error comes from the select statement query there

Comment: @GeorgeCrimson to be clear, is the value of data (the response from the server) 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0' or is that the error you are getting from trying to execute the code json = JSON.parse(data)?

Comment: The full error message shows: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (RetrieveLostItem.js:30)
    at r (framework7.js:12188)
    at XMLHttpRequest.g.onload (framework7.js:12363)

Comment: @NeilHibbert When I tried to click on certain button, it shows me the 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0', I used console.log() function and it pinpoints at JSON.parse(data)

Comment: @NeilHibbert Sequence is like this: lostid is pass to js, by using ajax, it is then post to php page, then in order to retrieve the data from php page, it is then passed back to js page (using $$.get() )

Comment: Try to see response from PHP in console with `console.log('this is data: ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));` this shows you what is PHP response exactly.

Comment: @ata tried to put the code above Json.parse(data) it gives me Notice: Undefined index: LostsItemID in C:\\wamp64\\www\\API\\RetrieveLostItemAPI.php issue instead, the unexpected json token still remains though

Comment: Is there a way to check whether the data has been passed to php?

Comment: I think I've found the issue: probably the LostItemid couldnt be passed to php page. "$lostsid = $_POST['LostsItemID']; " couldnt get LostItemID from js page

Answer (score 0):

remove `print_r($json);`

should be one output only

Comment: Removed, but it still shows the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 error :(

Answer (score 0):

`

```
$invoice_status = []; //global variable

foreach ($item_past_data as $key => $old_items) 
{
   if($old_items->item_id == $item_id)
   {
       if($old_items->item_name != $item_name)
       {
           $invoice_status = "Item name changed from ".$old_items->item_name." to ".$item_name;
       }
   }
}`
```

Comment: I declared the local variable as global variable. It solved the problem. Example shown above.